# Columns in a View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem. I have an HStack, whit 3 elements inside (Vstacks). I wanna center them, setting the center Vstack in the perfect center of the view. I share the code below and a screen

```
HStack (alignment: .center) {
    VStack (spacing:10) {
        WebImage(url: URL(string: "https://images.fotmob.com/image_resources/logo/teamlogo/\(matchDetails.general.homeTeam.id).png"))
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        Text(matchDetails.general.homeTeam.name)
            .font(.system(size: 15))
            .lineLimit(1)
    }.frame(alignment: .trailing)
    
    VStack (spacing: 10) {
        if let scoreStr = matchDetails.header.status.scoreStr {
            Text(scoreStr)
                .font(.system(size: 35))
                .fontWeight(.medium)
        } else if let matchTimeUTC = matchDetails.general.matchTimeUTC {
            Text(formatTime(from: matchTimeUTC))
                .font(.system(size: 35))
                .fontWeight(.medium)
        }
        
        if let reasonStr = matchDetails.header.status.reason?.long {
            Text(reasonStr)
                .font(.system(size: 15))
        } else if let liveTimeStr = matchDetails.header.status.liveTime?.long {
            Text(liveTimeStr)
                .font(.system(size: 15))
        }
    }
    
    VStack (spacing:10) {
        WebImage(url: URL(string: "https://images.fotmob.com/image_resources/logo/teamlogo/\(matchDetails.general.awayTeam.id).png"))
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        
        Text(matchDetails.general.awayTeam.name)
            .font(.system(size: 15))
            .lineLimit(1)
    }.frame(alignment: .leading)
}.padding(.horizontal)
}
    .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
```

[image: Simulator Screen]

Please, I need your help to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `maxWidth: .infinity` on the first and third `VStack` only. This way, they will both consume as much width as possible, each getting half of what is available. The middle `VStack` will be squeezed into the remaining space, exactly in the middle.

I don't think you need to set `trailing` and `leading` alignment either, it probably looks better without.

```swift
HStack {
    VStack(spacing:10) {
        // content as before
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // alignment also removed
    
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        // content as before
    }
    
    VStack(spacing:10) {
        // content as before
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // alignment also removed
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use maxWidths for that:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack (alignment: .center) {
        
        VStack (spacing:10) {
            Image(.pic1)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            Text("Long Long Long Text here")
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                .lineLimit(1) // <-- Play whit line limit maybe
        }
        .frame(alignment: .trailing)
        /// Limit the text sizes width
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        
        VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
            
            Text("20.30")
                .font(.system(size: 35))
                .fontWeight(.medium)
            
            Text("reasonStr")
                .font(.system(size: 15))
            
        }
        /// Add this
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        
        VStack (spacing:10) {
            Image(.pic2)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            
            Text("name")
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                .lineLimit(1)
        }
        .frame(alignment: .leading)
         /// Add this
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
}
```

Set maxWidth to .infinity so every view uses the same size and more lenghty texts won't affect other views. Increase lineLimit if you want more text to be visible.